# CSS elements within other CSS elements

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm a backend developer tasked withed moving a front end from a custom framework to React. (Spare a thought for me please).
I've come across CSS classes within other CSS classes such as:

```
    content.document{
       display: flex;
        .important{
         background-color: #FAD08A;
         padding: 20px 0;
         border-radius: 5px;
         position: relative;

          img.important{
            width: 70px;
            float: right;
          }
        
           h2 {
             font-size: 16px;
             color: #ccc;
             text-align: center;
             line-height: normal;
         }
    }
}
```

I have never seen this way of doing CSS and of course if I paste it into a normal CSS file, it doesn't work.

Is there a library that would all me to have CSS classes defined within other CSS classes (such as how h2 is defined in .important above)? I'd rather not have to modify tons of CSS to get this to work.

Comment: This code was likely written in SCSS files using the Sass preprocessor for CSS: https://sass-lang.com/

Comment: can you share the HTML as well? because of the class names

Answer (score 1):

This is [sass](https://sass-lang.com/). There is `sass` and `scss` syntax. The one you have above is `scss`. They have `.scss` or `.sass` file-types. Sass-Variant drops the brackets and works with indents alike `CoffeeScript` or `YAML`.

Since you are using React now, you can just install a "sass" package with `yarn add` or `npm install` command. There are different versions of sass because of legacy and different environments. You can decide if you want to install it locally (per project) or globally (-g flag for npm).

Usually, I go with the package named [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass). You could probably also use dart-sass. If you want to get fancy: [more-details-about-sass-variants](https://itnext.io/the-css-preprocessor-dilemma-node-sass-or-dart-sass-32a0a096572).

You can read more here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/.

This tool supports `sass` and `scss` with different setups: [sass playground](https://www.sassmeister.com)

Answer (score 0):

As Jon mentioned, it is written in SCSS. You can try to use an online tool that converts SCSS to CSS.